# Adobe InDesign CC 2017, can't open ExtendScript to edit script

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have a problem opening Adobe ExtendScript from Adobe InDesign (to edit the script). Once I click "edit script", Creative Cloud keeps popping up and nothing happens. I have installed Adobe ExtendScript already.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have fixed by disabling kaspersky and uninstalling the app. Thanks guys !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the [ExtendScriptToolKit](https://creative.adobe.com/products/estk) installed?
Did you try to open it at least once?
Can you run a script?
Did you try a different editor? ([Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) with [this](https://github.com/vamitul/RunInIndesign) package is great)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try sublime in future. For now, i have fixed by disabling kaspersky and reinstalling the app. :)